# Fill blank days in php calendar starting from monday

Tags: php, date, calendar, monthcalendar

I currently have a calendar built in php but I am struggling to fill the blank days before the first of the month using monday as the starting day.

The problem is when I get to a month starting with a sunday the week starts from sunday not monday as desired, I have fixed this by having an if statement and manually inserting 6 blank days if the month begins with a sunday but I wondered how I could do this without this manual check of a sunday.

The $dayOfWeek is got from the php function to get the day of the week so sunday is 0 through to saturday being 6.

Any way to do this or will I have to settle with my "ugly" manual sunday fix.

Basically I want to count the blank days before the day the month begins on.

```
// Fill Blank Days
for ($blankcounter = 1; $blankcounter < $dayOfWeek; $blankcounter++) {
        $calendar .= "<div class='single_day disable_day'><label>&nbsp</label></div><!--.single_day-->";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could keep your loop the same but adjust the variable earlier before the loop:

```
$dayOfWeek = $dayOfWeek ? $dayOfWeek : 7;
```

Or:

```
if ($dayOfWeek==0) $dayOfWeek = 7;
```

I guess you might of thought of these options before. Can't find anything better for now.